# What is a function which differs when differentiated with respect to x and then with y to function differentiated with respect to y and then x?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is a function which differs when differentiated with respect to $x$ and then with $y$ to function differentiated with respect to $y$ and then $x$? Even if it differs at one particular point.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Requirement_of_continuity

Comment: More advanced: [Can cross partial derivatives exist everywhere but be equal nowhere?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/104735)