# Why does the order not matter? Partial D

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, intuition

When taking partial derivatives, why does the order not matter as long as the function is continuous?

Any proof, intuitive or rigorous?

Comment: I think it actually requires second derivative to be continuous.

Comment: Try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPCKrVoTyD4

Comment: This is...Claurott's theorem, I believe, and yes, it has a proof, and it requires ths as above the second partials to be continuous on a disk around the point in question.  Intuitive reasoning:  If the function is continuous, it's continuous in every variable, so if we measure the mixed rates of change of x and y, it should be the same as measuring first y, then x, because everything is happening "smoothly" in both

Comment: Clairaut. And the proof should be easy to find in any multivariate calculus textbook...

Comment: Related: [Existence of mixed partials in Clairaut's theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98514/existence-of-mixed-partials-in-clairauts-theorem).

Comment: Also related: [Geometric interpretation of mixed partial derivatives?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/942538/856)

Answer (score 7):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ have continuous second derivatives on an open $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. Fix $y_0,y_1$ and let $$g(x):=\int_{y_0}^{y_1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)dy=f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_0).$$By assumption, $\partial f/\partial y$ is continuously differentiable, thus one can differentiate inside the integral and obtain $$\frac{dg}{dx}=\int_{y_0}^{y_1}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y)dy,$$or$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y_1)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y_0)=\int_{y_0}^{y_1}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y)dy.$$Fix $x,y_0$ and differentiate with respect to $y_1$ to obtain $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y_1)=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y_1).$$Note that actually, for this proof it is sufficient to assume continuity of $\partial^2f/\partial x\partial y$, and existence of $\partial f/\partial y$. To begin with, one doesn't even have to know that $\partial^2f/\partial y\partial x$ exists.