# Does one always have $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$?

Tags: partial-derivative

I would like to know if when we take a second partial derivative of a function do we always get:

$$\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x} \, \partial{y}} = \frac{\partial{^2u}}{\partial{y} \, \partial x}$$

if not, what does it mean about the function if the condition happens or not?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: See also this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29536/asymmetric-hessian-matrix/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is true **if** the function is of class $C^2$.

It is called [Schwarz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives).

A counter-example if the function is not $C^2$ would be:

$$f\colon(x,y)\mapsto\begin{cases} xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} &\text{ if $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$} \\ 0 &\text{ otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

For info, the graph of $f$ looks like this:

[image]