# Proving $\frac {\partial ^2 f}{\partial x\, \partial y} = \frac {\partial ^2 f}{\partial y \,\partial x}$ by the derivative theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, partial-derivative

> If I want to prove that $\dfrac {\partial ^2 f}{\partial x\, \partial y}
>  = \dfrac {\partial ^2 f}{\partial y \,\partial x}$, can I prove it by the definition of derivative using a double limit?

- I know how to do it, but I am not sure it's enough.
- The first condition is that the partial derivatives must exist and be continuous at my given point. The limit theorem says if the limit exists in some point $(x_0,y_0)$ then the examined function is continuous here. For the multivariable functions the limit exists if it doesn't matter if I calculate it first with respect to $x$ and then to $y$ and vice versa.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27s_theorem

Comment: See also [Schwarz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives)

Comment: This is my source. https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Clairaut's_theorem_on_equality_of_mixed_partials

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equality of mixed partial derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075714/equality-of-mixed-partial-derivatives) ; See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337004/does-one-always-have-f-xy-f-yx?noredirect=1&lq=1 ; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29536/asymmetric-hessian-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1 ;