# Which definitions of derivatives symmetrizes the Hessian matrix?

Tags: derivatives, hessian-matrix

[The Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) is a table of repeated derivatives. For some functions it is asymmetric. This seems to depend on the type of derivative being used. Which derivatives are suitable to make the Hessian matrix more symmetric?

Comment: The Hessian is symmetric when the function is $C^2$, meaning all of its second order partial derivatives are continuous. This is because of Schwartz's theorem. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: Fine! You can write that as an answer. We are however looking for functions like this and maybe the chosen derivative definition matters. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29536/asymmetric-hessian-matrix